# Whats the simplest way to make source and binary package when you are the original author?

Tags: packaging, debian

The Debian packaging guides, which I have read so far, assume that the packager is not the maintainer, and so needs to have original tarballs, patches, etc.

If I have an app which builds with "make" (not autotools, etc.) what sort of packaging guide do I need?

I don't want to make pointless tarballs and empty patches.

I do want source and binary packages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30582253/2072269? Also, if you use git, you can try `git-buildpackage`, which will simplify the tarball part for you. https://wiki.debian.org/PackagingWithGit#Using_the_upstream_repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian packaging as original author, those packages type is called *native*.

- `debian` folder is part of the source tree (source archive).
- No Debian patches.

**References:**

- [Debian developer reference - 5.4. Layout of the source package](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/pkgs.html#sourcelayout)
- [Debian Mentors FAQ - What is the difference between a native Debian package and a non-native package?](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq#What_is_the_difference_between_a_native_Debian_package_and_a_non-native_package.3F)

For guides, there are many but try to stick to Debian/Ubuntu official ones. Also, always verify its update date before engaging into it. I would recommend starting here:

[Debian packaging tutorial](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/packaging-tutorial/packaging-tutorial.en.pdf) which gives clear overview on the upstream workflow used by the distribution. (many tutorials miss that point)

Answer (score 1):

Nobody wants pointless anything. And rest assured, the communities that have adopted the .deb packaging (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, ...) have discussed beyond lengths about everything in there.

The basic idea about the packaging is that there is:

- a tarball that is nothing distribution-specific to argue with, which is the program's distribution-independent source tree. If that already knows how to behave in particular distributions - nice - if not, not. That is the tarball that has to be named yourname_version.orig.tar.(xz,gz,bz2) to be found when creating the package.
- a tarball that has everything that is specific to a particular release of Debian in a separate folder named - debian. One reason to have it separated, which the question already prepared for is that the individuals packaging are typically not the same as the ones that maintain the software itself. This helps when there is an update of the software so it cannot overwrite the packaging. And it rests assured that there are no hidden changes performed to the original source tree. And a RedHat developer would not want to see the debian-specific bits, so everyone is happy to have the debian folder separated from the rest.

So, there are the two tarballs. Not too much overhead, I tend to think. The main concern is the integrity of the upstream source tree.

Depending on where you live and about how social you are, there are different ways to start learning how to package. For many, just skimming through

- the Debian Policy https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ (surprisingly readable) and
- the Debian New Maintainer's Guide https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/

is all they ever want. Others are happy with

- the dh-make package that provides dh_make that basically auto-packages

and yet again others will have a look at

- https://wiki.debian.org/Keysigning/Offers

to meet up with a mostly social Debian Developer to be guided over the first steepest moments. Once you have some routine it is truly just a few minutes from 0 to an installable package, basically it is mostly the compile time that you wait for, so it is not too much to ask IMHO. Most work then goes into the package descriptions or also bits that upstream has not cared enough about like missing man pages or optional bits like the automated notification of updates.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The two things I do are:

1. Create the debian folder

   In the folder, I create the following files as required (i.e. do not create files you don't need):

   ```
    changelog
    compat
    control
    rules
    shlibs.local
    source/format
    source/options
    project-name.docs
    project-name.install
    project-name.preinst
    project-name.postinst
    project-name.prerm
    project-name.postrm
    project-name.service
    project-name.logrotate
    project-name.cron.daily
    project-name.cron.monthly
    ...
   ```
2. Then I build the package with:

   ```
    dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
   ```

   Really, I use a script. That command is going to litter your source tree with all sorts of files. So on my end I first make a copy then run the command in the copy. I can then delete the copy.

   ```
    cd project-name
    VERSION=`dpkg-parsechangelog --show-field Version`
    cd ..
    cp -r project-name project-name-${VERSION}
    cd project-name-${VERSION}
    dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
   ```

In the `debian/source/options` I have:

```
tar-ignore = "tmp"
tar-ignore = ".git"
```

because without these two, then those folders get added to your source package when it probably shouldn't.

Another way is to use the PPA system at https://launchpad.net/ and that has the advantage to be very easy to install the resulting package on any machine. It's also public if you want to share your resulting packages (if you don't want to share, then obviously you shouldn't use that one).